# Packaging a database with a full-stack Python application

Tags: python, json, database, postgresql, backend

I am currently creating an application that will be using Python Flask for the back-end and API and PostgreSQL as the database to store my data in JSON format. My plan is to have a front-end in JS to interact with the API which will pull relevant information from my database.

How do I package the database into the program so that if a fresh copy is pulled from GitHub, a user would have everything needed to host and use the service? I am still a new developer and having difficulty taking my hobbyist code and presenting it in a clean, organized way.

Thank you for all help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though your question leaves quite a few options open, here are two things you could do:

1. **If you assume your users can install a PostgreSQL database themselves**: you could dump the database which contains the minimum required to run your application (using [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/app-pgdump.html)). When your application starts on your user's server, it should detect the database it's connecting to is empty, which should trigger an import of your data. The only thing your users should do is fill out their database connection details
2. **If your users don't know anything about configuring servers**: You could create a [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) image containing your Python code and PostgreSQL. This package will contain all dependencies of your application and runs anywhere. Admittedly, this is a bit more 'advanced' and could lead to other difficulties both on your side as well as on your users.